# Using a tensor for k in tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k

Tags: tensorflow

I am using `tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k` for calculating my average precision. Now the problem is my k is not fixed between different calls to my function. So instead of using a constant k, I wanted to pass it every time(using a placeholder) to my function like this:

```
def calcMAP(tar, pred, num):
    labels = tf.cast(tar, tf.int64)
    metric, update = tf.metrics.sparse_average_precision_at_k(labels, pred, num)
    return update
```

But it seems tensorflow only accepts a constant number here instead of a tensor. So is there a way to get around this problem? Thanks